# Realtime plot animation from JupyterLab

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I've been using JupyterLab with matplotlib.pyplot for a while, and I wonder if there's some way to update plots and images from Python in realtime? (for example to show how loss function evolves)

Currently i've been using IPython.display.clear_output() function in loop to clear the output before plotting, but this creates horrible flickering. The solution doesn't have to be optimal, as I'm sure pyplot would be fast enough to render the data, but the problem is mainly the fact that the image doesn't update directly but instead the whole output has to be cleared first.

Answer (score 1):

That is possible with `matplotlib` and `ipywidgets`, lets try with `FuncAnimation` of `matplotlib`, it will creates an animation by repeatedly calling a function that draw on canvas.

edit: if you want to update the plot within your own data-generating loop lets try with IPython.display.display for your case then.

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

# Create a figure and a line object
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([], [])
display(fig)

x_data = []
y_data = []

# Your data-generating loop
for frame in range(100):
    x_data.append(frame)
    y_data.append(np.random.rand()*100)  # replace with your real data

    line.set_data(x_data, y_data)
    ax.relim() 
    ax.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
    clear_output(wait=True)
    display(fig)

plt.close()  # Close figure when done
```

Comment: Is there a way generate data in my loop and call matplotlib periodically to show it, instead of having matplotlib to call my function? Having my training loop be called by matplotlib would force me to write an update() function that runs for N iterations and that doesn't feel very handy

Comment: It also seems that this example doesn't work atleast in JupyterLab 3.6.3. If I try it like written, I get error "Javascript Error: IPython is not defined", and if I remove the "%matplotlib notebook" line, it draws an empty plot instead..

Comment: I've got several links to code that works in JupyterLab version 3.4.8 discussed in the top **text** section [here](https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/animated_matplotlib-binder/blob/master/index.ipynb). Make sure you use the links in that text because the code in the notebook itself is for the classic interface and not JupyterLab.

Comment: Not accepting the answer since it seems that what I want is not possible with JupyterLab..